# Live server does not show updates from SCSS in WebStorm

Tags: sass, compiler-errors, frontend, webstorm, npm-live-server

I have a problem with a live server. When I write SCSS, the live server does not show changes from time to time. If I delete some line of code and paste, it will show changes sometimes.

I have checked @import, all is connected. I also checked _ for SASS files. Just updated WebStorm to the latest version (using it for Front End).

What might be the issue?

Comment: what live server is meant? How do you transpile SASS?

Comment: live-server via npm installation. I use standart command to compile SASS. "npm run compile:sass"

Comment: And what is your actual programming Vannilla JS or any framework like Angular and React? All I can see is you are running only the sass not the complete server